# prepared statement with varable inpunt

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a prepared statement that has a variable amount of input variables.
for example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$types = "ssss";
$result_array = array of four different strings
$update = $conn->prepare($sql);
$update->bind_param($types,$result_array);
```

I know that this won't work but it's an example

note:

result_array, types and the fields in $sql always have the same amount as eachother

So if result_array has 5 values then $types and the values in $sql would also have 5

but it could variable in my code so 5 values could also be 6 or 2 values

so my question is:

Is it possible to have a variable amount of input values in an prepared statement

Comment: With PDO it's easy. With mysqli less easy but there are ways, people have done it before - you should be able to search for previous examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), but for this example, you have an array so you can count it and build what you need.  If you already have `$result_array`:

```
// build placeholders ?, ? based on array length
$vals = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($result_array), '?'));

// use $vals placeholders
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email, tel) VALUES ($vals)";

// build types based on array length *this is only string
$types = str_repeat('s', count($result_array));

$update = $conn->prepare($sql);

// unpack the array to individual arguments with splat ...    
$update->bind_param($types, ...$result_array);
```

**Note**:  If `$result_array` is an associative array (string indexes) then you will have to use `array_values` before using it in the `bind_param` with `...`.